# How can I use Tauri to create a directory in a user-selected directory?

Tags: typescript, permissions, dialog, tauri, create-directory

When I use the `createDir` method in **Tauri** + Typescript, I have to specify a base directory (`dir`) in the `FsDirOptions`. But I want to give the user himself the possibility to choose a target directory. Can I convert the selected destination path to an [fs path constant](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/fs#basedirectory) (such as `fs.BaseDirectory.AppLocalData`) with so that I can put the numeric value in the `FsDirOptions`?

```
import {open} from '@tauri-apps/api/dialog';
import {basename} from '@tauri-apps/api/path';
import {createDir} from '@tauri-apps/api/fs';

// 1. the user can choose a destination directory
open({
  directory: true,
  multiple: false
}).then((directory) => {

  // 2. the path to the destination directory is decomposed so that we know the name of the destination directory
  basename(directory).then((name) => {

    const dir = ...?   // only the path to the directory without the basename. I think I have to convert this to u16 for the use in FsDirOptions?

    // 3. the directory will be created
    createDir(name, {dir, recursive: true}).then(() => {
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

When I specify the path as a string in the `FsDirOptions` under `dir`, I get an error message that a string was passed but u16 was expected.
This speaks for the fact that you can only use [fs path constants](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/fs#basedirectory). Probably this is also related to the fact that in *tauri.conf.json* under `tauri.allowlist.fs.scope` exactly these paths have to be enabled? But surely it must be possible for the user to choose where to export to?

Comment: You don't have to specify a base dir. You can give createDir the unmodified path the dialog returned and it should work. The scope is also irrelevant since the dialog will expand the scope automatically.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much! I didn't realize that you can also specify the absolute path directly and don't have to specify a base dir in the FsDirOptions.